# Why is store_result() not returning num_rows equivalent to mysqli Regular Statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been combing through previous questions and trying many solutions but cannot figure this out.  I'm trying to convert this query to a Prepared Statement:

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE user_to='$userLoggedIn' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Here is what I have:

```
        $query = $this->con->stmt_init();
        $query->prepare('SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE user_to=? ORDER BY id DESC');
        $query->bind_param('s', $userLoggedIn);
        $query->execute();
        $query->store_result();

        $qty = $query->num_rows;
        $query_result = $query->get_result();
```

Below this code I have variables being used like this:

```
        if($qty == 0) {
            echo "<li class='no-more-posts' style='height: 0px; text-transform: uppercase;'>- You have no notifications! -</li>";
            return;
        }

        $num_iterations = 0; //Number of messages checked 
        $count = 1; //Number of messages posted

        while($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if($num_iterations++ < $start)
            continue;

        if($count > $limit)
            break;
        else 
            $count++;

        $user_from = $row['user_from'];

   etc.etc.
```

What I am getting is blank result in my dropdown.  If I change the `while` statement back to the original `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {` (which I know is wrong and from old statement)  my result is always returning the `li` No More Posts to Show.  This tells me that `$qty = $query->num_rows;` is returning 0.  Based on documentation my understanding is that once I buffered the result set with `store_result()` I could call `$qty = $query->num_rows;` right after.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I'd get rid of `store_result()` completely. `prepare()`, `bind_param()`, `execute()`, `get_result()`, and then `fetch_all()`. Use the resulting array in a simple `foreach` loop. (Actually I'd use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and then this would be 3 lines of code.)

Comment: 3 lines of code sounds nice.  Will have to get on the PDO sometime.  I did it in 12! lol.  Had to break them up, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm certain this isn't the most efficient way to do things, but it's all I have on it; decided to break the statement up.

First I did a statement for the count:

```
    $query_count = $this->con->stmt_init();
    $query_count->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notifications WHERE user_to=?');
    $query_count->bind_param('s', $userLoggedIn);
    $query_count->execute();

    $query_count_result = $query_count->get_result();
    $rows_count = $query_count_result->fetch_array();

    $qty = array_shift($rows_count);
```

Then I did a statement for the data:

```
        $query = $this->con->stmt_init();
        $query->prepare('SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE user_to=? ORDER BY id DESC');
        $query->bind_param('s', $userLoggedIn);
        $query->execute();

        $query_result = $query->get_result();
```

It solved my problem & everything works as expected.  I know there is a better way to do this, so if someone has that suggestion great.  In the meantime this will have to do.

Comment: In you second block of code, you add `$data = $query_result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` and then you have an array with your data in it. Your count is `$qty = count($data);` and later in your code you can just `foreach ($data as $row) {...}`